# Custom segmented control

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to create a segmented control which is looking like this.

[image]

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try with custom UIButtons and handle their UITouchUpInside events and make a feel like segmented controls.

Comment: Why not. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

It is probably of no use for you, but here is the how you can create a segmented control that resembles your image above.

First you create a standard control with as little adjustments in interface builder as possible. You don't even have to set the title, which I did anyway. This is shown in the pictures below.

[image]

[image]

Then in the view controller in which you have an outlet to the segmented control, you put the following code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var lesGroupes: UISegmentedControl!

    //MRK: - Properties
    var tousGroupes = "Tous les groupes"
    var mesGroupes = "Mes Groupes suivis"
    var tousCounter = 34
    var mesCounter = 0
    var attributesTousGroupes = []
    var attributesMesGroupes = []
    var dividerImage = UIImage(named: "dividerImage")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Clear the border colors of the segmented control and put in the divider image. The image you can pcik yourself. I just got one of the internet.
        self.lesGroupes.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.lesGroupes.setDividerImage(self.dividerImage, forLeftSegmentState: .Normal, rightSegmentState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)

        //Now adjust the title of the segmented control. I assumed the numbers are some counter telling the user the number of people in the groups.
        self.tousGroupes.appendContentsOf(" (\(self.tousCounter))")
        self.mesGroupes.appendContentsOf(" (\(self.mesCounter))")

        //Once the new title strings are defined the titles of the segmented controls can be set.
        self.lesGroupes.setTitle(self.tousGroupes, forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
        self.lesGroupes.setTitle(self.mesGroupes, forSegmentAtIndex: 1)

        //Please, remember. You set the entire color of the segmented control to clearcolor, which means no color. Now you have to set the title color of each segment seperately. I assumed when the segment is selected, you want the color to be red and the standard color is black.
        self.lesGroupes.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()], forState: .Normal)
        self.lesGroupes.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()], forState: .Selected)
    }
}
```

The result of this example looks like this in the simulator.
[image]

Please, let me know if this is what you were actually looking for.

Kind regards,
MacUserT